# Activate USB Microphone in VB.Net

Tags: usb, microphone

I would like some help if possible. What I want to do is simply be able to hear the microphone over the top of a track playing for Karaoke purposes. I don't want to record the input but being able to turn the mic ON and  control the mic input volume would be handy.

I'm using VS2015, Winforms and .net2 as using program in XP.

The mic I'm using is a Logitech USB Microphone.

All help most welcomed.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Every hardware device usually has a driver which you can interface with.. try searching the vendor's website for an SDK- it usually comes with examples on how to communicate with the device.. If the device only has c/c++ drivers, not all is lost since you can use P/Invoke to work with it.. However I would look out for a .NET driver- they are quite common these days.

Comment: Probably a little over my head but am looking and I learn fast. Driver wise the mic installs without need for extra drivers as both XP and Win10 find them so at least their not obscure ones. As said above I don't want to do anything fancy with it, just enable it so can hear through speakers if make a noise down mic and if possible control its volume but that's about it. Thx for the guidance though at least its a direction to look in.

Comment: There is a difference between OS driver and SDK driver.. SDK Driver enables developers to communicate with the device.. Search the Logitech site for an SDK, or Software Development Kit. It usually comes with code examples and the kind of driver a developer needs in the form of dll files